# Retrieve a value from a generic List<T> using LINQ in a foreach statement

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

I assume this is a silly(simple) question but i've not been able to find the answer, I can use LINQ effectively for XML (That's the entirety of my LINQ experience) but when I try to get the actual value as a string from a generic list or List (Included in description), I only get something like "{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator}" where I would like it to say "scrambled-eggs.jpg"

```
private static List<Recipe> currentRecipeList = new List<Recipe>();
public static List<Recipe> CurrentRecipeList { get { return currentRecipeList; } set { currentRecipeList = value; } }//Populated from an XML document 

public static string GetSpecificRecipeValue(string recipeName, int index, int ingredientIteration = -1, int ingredientValue = -1)//From CurrentRecipeList get value(Index) where recipeName is equal to CurrentRecipeList.RecipeName.
    {
        IEnumerable<string> recipeElement = null;
        IEnumerable<string> ingredientElement = null;
        if (index == 0)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeType); }
        else if (index == 1)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeName ); }
        else if (index == 2)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeSource); }
        else if (index == 3)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeID); }
        else if (index == 4)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipePicture); }
        else if (index == 5)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeDescription); }
        else if (index == 6)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeMethod); }
        else if (index == 7)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeCost); }
        else if (index == 8)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeDifficulty); }
        else if (index == 9)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeServings); }
        else if (index == 10)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipePreparationTime); }
        else if (index == 11)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeCookingTime); }
        else if (index == 12)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeGlobalRating); }
        else if (index == 13)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeUserRating); }
        else if (index == 14)
        { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where el.RecipeName == recipeName select el.RecipeTags); }
        else if (index == 15 && ingredientValue == 0)
        { ingredientElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where el.RecipeName == recipeName select el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].Item); }
        else if (index == 15 && ingredientValue == 1)
        { ingredientElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].Quantity); }
        else if (index == 15 && ingredientValue == 2)
        { ingredientElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].Unit.ToString()); }
        else if (index == 15 && ingredientValue == 3)
        { ingredientElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].State); }
        else if (index == 15 && ingredientValue == 4)
        { ingredientElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].Type); }

        else
        { recipeElement = null; ingredientElement = null; }


        if (recipeElement != null)
        {
            return recipeElement.ToString();
        }
        else if (ingredientElement != null)
        {
            return ingredientElement.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The Recipe Class...

```
public class Recipe
{

    public string RecipeType { get; set; }
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }
    public string RecipeSource { get; set; }
    public string RecipeID { get; set; }
    public string RecipePicture { get; set; }//File name of Picture to read from pictures folder
    public string RecipeDescription { get; set; }//ShortDescription 
    public string RecipeMethod { get; set; }
    public string RecipeCost { get; set; }
    public string RecipeDifficulty { get; set; }
    public string RecipeServings { get; set; }
    public string RecipePreparationTime { get; set; }
    public string RecipeCookingTime { get; set; }
    public string RecipeGlobalRating { get; set; }
    public string RecipeUserRating { get; set; }
    public string RecipeTags { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }

}
```

The Ingredients Class..

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any more information, this is my first post and although i've been racking my brain, google and stackoverflow, the answer eludes me. Any other methods of getting a specific piece of information from the RecipeName as a the argument or Sources where I could learn this information myself, would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
Ok, here is the correct solution as a returned result thanks to BJ Myers.

```
private static List<Recipe> currentRecipeList = new List<Recipe>();
public static List<Recipe> CurrentRecipeList { get { return currentRecipeList; } set { currentRecipeList = value; } }//Populated from an XML document.
public static string GetSpecificRecipeValue(string recipeName, int index, int ingredientIteration = -1, int ingredientValue = -1)//From CurrentRecipeList get value(Index) where recipeName is equal to CurrentRecipeList.RecipeName.
{
    IEnumerable<string> recipeElement = null;
    IEnumerable<string> ingredientElement = null;
    if (index == 0)
    { recipeElement = (from el in currentRecipeList where recipeName == el.RecipeName select el.RecipeType); }
    else if (index == 1)
...

if (recipeElement != null)
        {
            string result = recipeElement.FirstOrDefault<string>().ToString();
            return result;
        }
        else if (ingredientElement != null )
        {
            return ingredientElement.FirstOrDefault<string>().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Using the `where` clause returns a *collection* of elements, not just one.  (It actually returns a class that implements `IEnumerable`, such as the `WhereSelectListIterator`.  If you want a single item, you need to use `.First` or `.FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, I'll give Kudos and post results in a few moments.

Comment: As a side note, C# has different built-in data types, not only strings. Are you coming from javascript environment?:)

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser Yes, I did start with Java but I only ever used basic arrays and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: `.FirstOrDefault`from  returns the required value rather than the class that implements IEnumerable.

```
string result = recipeElement.FirstOrDefault<string>().ToString();
        return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as provided by Thomas, is to use `.FirstOrDefault()`. But, just to help out with your code, I thought I'd show you a shorter way to do what you're doing. Try this:

```
public static string GetSpecificRecipeValue(string recipeName, int index, int ingredientIteration = -1, int ingredientValue = -1)//From CurrentRecipeList get value(Index) where recipeName is equal to CurrentRecipeList.RecipeName.
{
    Func<Recipe, string>[] properties = new Func<Recipe, string>[]
    {
        el => el.RecipeType,
        el => el.RecipeName,
        el => el.RecipeSource,
        el => el.RecipeID,
        el => el.RecipePicture,
        el => el.RecipeDescription,
        el => el.RecipeMethod,
        el => el.RecipeCost,
        el => el.RecipeDifficulty,
        el => el.RecipeServings,
        el => el.RecipePreparationTime,
        el => el.RecipeCookingTime,
        el => el.RecipeGlobalRating,
        el => el.RecipeUserRating,
        el => el.RecipeTags,
    };

    Func<Recipe, string>[] ingredients = new Func<Recipe, string>[]
    {
        el => el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].Item,
        el => el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].Quantity,
        el => el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].Unit,
        el => el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].State,
        el => el.RecipeIngredients[ingredientIteration].Type,
    };

    return
        currentRecipeList
            .Where(el => recipeName == el.RecipeName)
            .Select(el =>
                index < 15
                    ? properties[index](el)
                    : ingredients[ingredientValue](el))
            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, after I've completed this class and know the rest of my code works, I'm going to use your solution, partially because I don't yet know how it works.

Comment: @SirajMansour - No, it doesn't. It would only fail if any of the `Func<Recipe, string>` were executed. During initialization they are not.